# How does the look up time of nested dictionaries increase?

Tags: python, dictionary, time, time-complexity, lookup

Can someone comment on how the complexity of dictionaries increases as we "nest" them further?

E.g as I add an element as follows:

```
dict_name[a][b][c][d] = 0
```

I would think the lookup time should be the same for any dictionary (constant time O(1)), but would it change significantly if I add elements like this?

```
dict_name[a][b][c]....[z]
```

Comment: Are you conscious that the array of dimension 26 will hold at least 2^26=67108864 different dictionaries (assuming every dimension allows 2 distinct values; and 2541865828329 dictionaries for 3 values per dimension, which is far beyond what a PC can handle) ?

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the concept of `O(1)`. If you do an `O(1)` operation a fixed number of times you still get `O(1)`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22188943/3936732) SO answer explains why the constant element doesn't matter (except that it does).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for clarifying that.. I was curious what impact a nested dictionary would have on both time and memory :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's dictionary implementation doesn't change with nesting, no, so the algorithmic complexity of a lookup does not change. As far as Python is concerned, each `[key]` subscription is independent from where the object you are subscribing came from.

Each lookup is still O(1). Looking up a nested element is then *depth* times a O(1) lookup. Since you hard-coded the depth (by using literal notation), what you have is still O(1) as a constant multiplier doesn't affect Big-O complexity.

Answer (score 4):

```
dict_name[a][b][c][d] = 0
```

This is essentially the same as the following

```
temp_a = dict_name[a]
temp_b = temp_a[b]
temp_c = temp_b[c]
temp_c[d] = 0
```

So you just have three lookups, in which you get an object from a dictionary which just happens to be another dictionary. And then, in the final step, you make one dictionary assignment.

As [we know](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict), dictionary lookups take all constant time on average, so all those four operations are O(1) themselves. Combined, you get 4 × O(1), which is still O(1) (because constant factors are not significant for big O).

If you now increase the depth of that nesting, all you get is more `temp_y = temp_x[k]` lines, which again is constant time. So you only increase the factor `k` in k × O(1). And as said before, as long as `k` is constant, the factor is not significant for big O, so you stay at constant time, regardless of your nesting depth.