# Big Oh Analysis Result

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I just formulated an algorithm for a problem and I analysed it to be O(2m+n) but we are supposed to get O(m+n) so I want to know if O(2m+n) = O(m+n).

Comment: For Big-O analysis in the common sense, given that `m` and `n` are two independent variables, `O(m+n)` itself would generally reduce to `O(m)` or `O(n)` depending on which variable we choose to study (in the context on the asymptotic behaviour of our algorithm w.r.t. one of these variables). _"The implicit assumption is that these properties extend to more than one variable. In this paper, we demonstrate that this assumption, which seems to pervade the computing literature, is invalid."_ from [On Asymptotic Notation with Multiple Variables](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) [ignores constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis). So `O(m +n)` is the same as `O(100000m + 50n)`

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too just wanted to confirm.