# When comparing running time how to determine which values to drop

Tags: algorithm

For example.
O(n(n+1))
Would this simply simplify to n^2
Because n^2+n you would drop the n

Also
2000n^2
Would simply be n^2

Also
0.001n^3 would simply be n^3

Is this correct?

Comment: I believe all three scenarios are correct. Edit: to answer your question, just drop the constant. `O(n)` et al does not *really* care about them even if they *are* significant. This is covered well enough in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis

Answer (score 0):

`O(n(n+1))` would simplify to `O(n^2)` because `n(n+1)` is less than or equal to a constant factor of `n^2`, for sufficiently large n:

`n(n + 1) <= n^2 + n <= n^2 + n^2 <= 2n^2`

The other simplifications are correct, because you're just removing a constant factor.

Basically, you can remove a constant factor, and any slower growing terms from the expression.