# Basic Time Complexity 10 = O(n)

Tags: big-o

> Saying f
>   = O ( g ) is a  very loose analog of  f <= g
>    It differs from the usual notion of  because of the constant c , so that for instance 10
>   n
>   = O ( n )

This came from my textbook how can 10n <= n when n is clearly below 10n on a graph?

I just started learning about big O notation and I am completely lost.

Comment: They said it was very loose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good explanation at [Why is constant always dropped from big O analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis) but we drop the constants.

Another way to think of it is that 10n is basically the same as n if you are a long way away and n is very large when you compare that function to other functions. n^2 is basically the same as 10n^2 when you compare these quadratic functions with the linear function we started with.

let n = 1,000,000. Then n = 1,000,000 and 10n = 10,000,000. n^2 = 1,000,000,000,000 and 10n^2 = 10,000,000,000,000

Now let n = 1,000,000,000,000. Then n = 1,000,000,000,000 and 10n = 10,000,000,000,000. n^2 = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 and 10n^2 = 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

As n gets larger, a linear function with any constant will get closer and closer to the value of n compared to other classes of functions, and a quadratic function will get closer and closer to the value of n^2 compared to other classes of functions.

In our example, when n is 1 with a million zeros, who cares about one more zero in linear time because in quadratic time there's a million more zeros.