# How to find runtime complexity of a java method

Tags: java, data-structures

I have following method

```
int function(int n) {
    if(n<20) {
        return 19;
    }
    return 20 + function(n/2) + function(n/2);
}
```

I believe that the runtime complexity with `function(n/2)` is `O(log(n))`. But I am confused about this. Can anyone explain the runtime complexity for this method. I would really appreciate your effort.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you return `return 20+2*function(n/2)`?

Comment: @clinomaniac I have no problem with that. But what happens to my runtime complexity?

Comment: Technically it stays the same. Still will be `O(log n)` since you are reducing the problem by half every time. `O(2 log n)` = `O(log n)`

Comment: Remember constants get dropped out of big O complexities. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis  So if you do `function(n/2)` 2, 4 or 10 times as long as its constant it wont matter for big O (at its current location)

Comment: Oh.. I didnt realise that. I was just focusing that when it is called twice from the same method it would make it O(2^n) and eventually it would change  O(log n)

Comment: @ug_ Thanks for the link. It really helped me understand that concept ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be o(2^(log n)) = O(log n).
Consider an example of taking n = 64. if the base case was not 20 which we can think of as constant it will take 64 lines of execution at each step.
Example- f(64) = 20+f(32)+f(32) = 1 line and for calculation f(32)= 20+f(16)+f(16) there are 2 f(32) so at here it will be 2 lines and at every downstep it will multiply current no. of current lines with 2 and so on.