# what size do we consider the pointer of 2d array in space complexity?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

[image]

This is the code given in my algorithms book.We need to calculate its space complexity.

this is the answer given-

[image]

The space **complexity** is `S=C+Sp` and in this case `Sp` is zero as the code is independent of `n`.
But I wanted to calculate the C part of the code and in this case it would be `5*2bytes=10 bytes` considering `a,x,n,0 and -1.`

So my question is what would be the C in case a was a 2d matrix,do we consider it as `2 bytes` only as in the case of 1d array or we take it as 4 bytes?

Comment: 0 is a somewhat uncommon answer, I would have said O(1).

Comment: This is not asymptotic notation

Comment: Firstly, it is in asymptotic notation (The legendary Big-O). Secondly, I don't think you have to use 4 bytes, since that'll only change if you switch to a 64-bit system from a 32-bit one.

Comment: @NitinPawar do we use the space required for 2-d array to be double that of 1 d array or the same?

Comment: That is uncertain. It will be double only in the case of n x 2 matrix. It can expand further, depending on the other dimension of your matrix.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Constant factors are irrelevant in asymptotic complexity - 1 bit and 1 TB would give you the same answer.

Comment: [What is a plain English explanation of “Big O” notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation) [Why is constant always dropped from big O analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis)

Comment: @Dukeling: as the OP already said, he is not after asymptotic complexities but exact complexities. (Whether this makes sense or not in the O(1) case is another matter.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not familiar with the concept of "exact complexities". If this is about "the exact amount of space used", that will come down to the specific programming language, operating system and system architecture used (among other factors).

Comment: @Dukeling: this is obviously C++ and it might be that the book refers to the old 16 bits architecture. The OS has little to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers and integers are no more 16 bits since the mid-eighties so I wonder what you mean with your 2 bytes.

Also note that your accounting of space is a little weird. You don't count the variable i, but you do count literal constants, which usually appear as immediate arguments in the assembly code.

Anyway, on a 32 bits machine, all addresses (and pointers) are represented on 4 bytes and the extra accounting of array dimensions is performed by the compiler and hard-coded into the assembly.

On a 64 bits machine, count 8 bytes per pointer and 4 bytes per int.