# Time complexity for nested n/2

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I know time complexity for nested loop of n is O(n^2). But If I have the nested loop of as below,

```
for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
  for(j=0;j<n/2;j++)
    ...
    ...
```

How to calculate time complexity for this code. Is it also O(n^2)? If it is, how?

Comment: this is the same complexity as if you were dividing by 1, i.e. not dividing, as the number you are dividing by is a constant number. You could divide it by a million, and the complexity is still O(n^2). If, however, you divided it by n, or a derivative of n, it would change. E.g. `for (i = 0; i < n/(n/2); i++)....` it would have a different complexity.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it also O(n^2)? If it is, how?

Yes, it is.

All you have to do is count the total number of iterations (which is `n/2 * n/2 = n^2 / 4` by the product rule), and bear in mind that Big-O notation ignores constants. Asymptotic analysis drops constants because they don't matter when `n` tends to infinity. In other words, `f(n) = n` and `g(n) = 2n` are both linear functions, despite the fact that `g` grows faster than `f`. Asymptotic analysis only cares about classes of growth rates.

See also:

- [Why is constant always dropped from big O analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis)
- [Why are we allowed to ignore coefficients in Big-O notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074136/why-are-we-allowed-to-ignore-coefficients-in-big-o-notation/2074157#2074157)