# What is the runtime of this code in Theta Notation?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I believe that the runtime of func2 is O(n * log(n)).
  But some people have told me that it's not.

```
int func2(int* arr, int n){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2)
        reverseArray(arr, i);
    }
}

void reverseArray(int* arr, int n){
    int left, right, temp;

    for (left = 0, right = n-1; left <= right; left++, right--){
        temp = arr[left];
        arr[left] = arr[right];
        arr[left] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `reverseArray()` runs in O(n) time and is executed O(log n) times therefore the time complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: Is `for(i=1;i<=n;i*=2)` O(log(n)) or O(0.5n) therefore O(n)?

Comment: If `n == 64`, then i goes `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64`. Is  7 closer to log(n) or 0.5n?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The time complexitiy of `reverseArray()` is indeed O(n), but it depends on the variable `i`, not `n`. As @santanu kar shows, the total run-time complexity is a sum of a geometric series with log(n) terms that grows exponentially, hence linear.

Comment: @dobkind Ah that's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`func2` runs in linear time, i.e., `O(n)`

Explanation:

It's easy to say time complexity of reverseArray method is linear, i.e., `big-Theta(n)`

let's assume `func2` is called with `n = 8`;

The calls to reverseArray will be:-

```
reverseArray(arr, 1)
reverseArray(arr, 2)
reverseArray(arr, 4)
reverseArray(arr, 8)
```

So total runtime = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15, i.e. 2*8 - 1

So, if n was a power of 2, total run time = `O(2*n - 1)`

If n was not a power of 2, total run time would be = `O(2*K - 1)`, where K is the highest power of 2 less than n. We can safely say, `O(2*K - 1) = O(2*n - 1)` [since, O is upperbound]

`O(2*n - 1) = O(n)`

For theta notation, lower bound is `O(2*K - 1)`, where K is the highest power of 2 less than n.
Therefore, time complexity = `Theta(2^(floor(log(n)base2)+1))`

Comment: O(2*n - 1) = O(n) . What?

Comment: @DamianSiniakowicz for asymptotic notations, we ignore constants.
For more clarification, you can refer this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis