# Is O(n*d) similar to O(n) where d is the constant

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm new to time complexity and etc and trying to figure which algorithm is better.Might not be the best question of all time but yeah :/

Comment: They are not just similar, [they are the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis

Answer (score 1):

If `d` is a constant then `O(d*n)` and `O(n)` are the same thing. This is what Big-O is all about i.e. the fact that these two are considered the same Big-O is part of the definition of Big-O.

The definition of Big-O is basically that for large `n's` some function `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if there exists a constant `k` such that `f(n) ≤ k * g(n)`.

In your case, `d` is just absorbed by the constant `k` in that definition. A suitable constant `k` clearly exists: `d*n ≤ k*n`as long as `k` is greater than `d`.