# Space Complexity two 1d arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, space-complexity

```
int arr1[N];
int arr2[N];
```

If we are using arr1 and arr2 in the program what will be the overall space complexity of the program `O(n^2)` or `O(n)`?

Comment: By `O(n2)`, do you mean `O(n*2)` or `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Space complexity means how much extra memory your algorithm takes to solve a problem. If there it declares 2 one dimensional arrays of size in then its size complexity will be O(2n).

Comment: Two things of size N take up the same space as one thing of size 2*N.

Comment: possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188851/why-is-the-constant-always-dropped-from-big-o-analysis spoiler alert it is O(n)

Comment: nitpick: space complexity is about how memory consumption varies with increasing `N`, though in your example `N` is a compile time constant. Hence, it is questionable to talk about space complexity of the compiled program. Once complied the space complexity is a constant

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde by O(n2) I mean O(n^2)

Comment: @NakulAmate Please add the code snippet in which you are trying to use this Arrays